# Plotting graphs using pixel coordinates

Tags: python, matplotlib, pixel

Is there a way to plot a line graph using pixel coordinates instead of data coordinates in python using the matplotlib library ?

The reason is the following:
I want to plot a brightness vs time line graph. But I want to plot the data that I have using pixel coordinates. Example: If the time is hour 0 min 4 and the brightness of the image at that time is 130. I want to plot the point at [2,130]-these coordinates are in pixels.

Comment: [This](https://matplotlib.org/users/transforms_tutorial.html) might help?

Comment: yes, but what that page basically describes is how to convert between the data coordinate system and the display coordinate system. I am looking to plot  my line graph using pixel coordinates from the beginning. Not converting the data i have.

Comment: What are you actually wanting to do?

Comment: i want to plot a brightness vs time line graph. But i want to plot the data that i have using pixel coordinates. Ex if the time is hour 0 min 4 and the brightness of the image at that time is 130. I want to plot the point at [2,130]-these coordinates are in pixels.

Comment: Any particular reason you need to plot in pixels? Could you also update your question with this example, it may help others with any answers.

Comment: There is no reason to use pixels in the example case. But if you need to use pixels, [the transforms tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/users/transforms_tutorial.html) is indeed the correct place to start. If you have a problem with implementation, why not show the code you have so far and clearly state the problem.

Comment: If you indeed want to use pixels, another approach is to [work directly with images](http://www.scipy-lectures.org/advanced/image_processing/) and draw your data on a white page. Just keep in mind that the result will look bad unless you spent plenty of time adjusting a lot of things. Matplotlib exist to avoid it.